# Why can't I write to this buffer?

Tags: c++, c

A really simple `mmap` and write in a for loop. All I am trying to do it make the value of each byte 255.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

int main()
{
    void *Buffer = mmap(0,
                        BUFFER_SIZE,
                        PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                        MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS,
                        -1,
                        0);
    uint8_t *Byte = (uint8_t *)Buffer;
    for (int i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE - 1; ++i) 
    {
        *Byte++ = 0xFF;
        printf("%u", *Byte);
    }
    munmap(Buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
    return 0;
}
```

For some reason my output is all 0's. What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The statement `*Byte++ = 0xFF` writes `0xFF` at the location pointed to by the pointer and advances the pointer itself. The next statement prints the adjacent byte which is still zero.

Comment: Well now I'm embarrassed. I'll accept as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

Because you call `printf` after the pointer is already incremented, so you always print unfilled memory.

```
*Byte = 0xFF;
printf("%u", *Byte);
++Byte;
```

Answer (score -1):

The ***Byte** is pointing to the next pointer after Byte++.